# oauth response with restsharp for zoho

Tags: oauth-2.0, zoho

I am trying to get an access token from the ZOHO api per their documentation.  I am using the RestSharp package. I already have a grant token and ZOHO requires the parameters to be passed in the body for client_id, client_secret, and grant_type.  However my sample code returns no response.  Any idea what I am missing in my code?

```
    TokenUrl = "https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/token"

    Try
        client = New RestClient(TokenUrl)
        request = New RestRequest(TokenUrl, Method.POST)
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json")
        request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer " & Grant_Token)
        request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json")
        request.AddParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code", ParameterType.GetOrPost)
        request.AddParameter("client_id", Client_ID, ParameterType.GetOrPost)
        request.AddParameter("client_secret", Client_Secret, ParameterType.GetOrPost)
        request.AddParameter("code", Grant_Token, ParameterType.GetOrPost)
        response = client.Execute(request)
```

Nothing is returned in the response and the status code is zero.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check, if you are exactly using zoho "com" or "eu". Check if this code works with "eu".